# Create relationship on tables for both ID and TIMESTAMP

Tags: join, powerbi, relationship

I have two tables which save data each day.

Table1:

- timestamp/id_1/value1/value2
- 01.01.2020/123/asdf/xyz
- 02.01.2020/123/asdf/xyz12
- 03.01.2020/222/asdf/ertw

Table2:

- timestamp/id_2/value1/id_1
- 01.01.2020/345/asdfx/123
- 02.01.2020/345/asdfy/123
- 03.01.2020/678/asdfc/222

There is a relationship between both tables:

- Table2 * : 1 Table1

The problem when I create the relationship is, that it doesnt recognize the timestamp.

Do you have any idea how to realize setting up the relationship by ID AND by timestamp?
So that:
"02.01.2020/345/asdfy/123" relates to "02.01.2020/123/asdf/xyz12"
and:
"01.01.2020/345/asdfx/123" relates to "01.01.2020/123/asdf/xyz"

Thank you very much!
I am building the data model in PowerBI.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate the columns for unique id in power query (or in the source, or sql) and use it for connect